# How to change '-' from all Shopify product links to '+'

Tags: shopify

By default shopify creates all links in the format of .../products/a-pair-of-wolves

I want to change all links and create any future links in the format of .../products/a+pair+of+wolves

Is there a way to do this without using url redirects?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Shopify removes special characters and format it in nicer way for CEO.

Eg: if you pass `black+passport+c+ @ -- yo &cover` as handle (using admin panel or REST API) you will get `black-passport-c-yo-cover`.